# como faço pra imprimir a linha que está o menor elemento de uma matriz?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m[4][4],i,j,menor;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
           cin>>m[i][j];
           if (i == 0 and j == 0){
               menor=m[0][0];
           }
           if(m[i][j]<menor){
            menor=m[i][j];
           }
        }
    }

    cout<<"O menor numero e:"<<menor<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, **você quer o número da linha do valor inserido e não da matriz**. Para ambas as formas, você pode monitorar as inserções (variável `insercoes`) e guardar o valor da inserção menor em uma variável (nesse caso `linhaDoMenorNumero`) ou atualizar a variável com o índice da linha atual da sua matriz (variável `i`):

```
int m[4][4], i, j, menor, linhaDoMenorNumero, insercoes = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       cin >> m[i][j];
       insercoes++;

       if (i == 0 and j == 0) {
           menor = m[0][0];
       }

       if(m[i][j] < menor) {
        // para encontrar a linha da matriz, basta substituir "insercoes" por "i"
        linhaDoMenorNumero = insercoes;
        menor = m[i][j];
       }
    }
}

cout << "O menor numero e: " << menor << endl;
cout << "Na linha: " << linhaDoMenorNumero << endl;
return 0;
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: muito obrigada!